# LWC with jVectorMap >> WARNING: Unsupported [object HTMLCollection] method: window. Returning undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm attempting to use jVectorMaps in an LWC component.  If you view https://jvectormap.com/tutorials/getting-started/ there are a number of jQuery resources that require loading.  I've added the resources to zipped static resource file and have been trying to use them in my LWC.  One issue I noted was there was a dependency between each .JS file therefore I require to load them in promises one after the other based on their order. A bit strange and probably not a good approach I know but I was trying this out as a POC.

I then try to apply the Jvectormap once all resources are loaded and I receive a WARNING "WARNING: Unsupported [object HTMLCollection] method: window. Returning undefined"
The functionality does not work and I'm guessing the warning is a factor.

The code below is a sample of the code I was trying. The resources load ok and on debugging $('#world-map-125'). (e.g. console.log ('Check if found ' + ($('#world-map-125') === undefined));
My div is being found ok.

I was wondering if people are familiar with the error or if it would be jVectorMap specific. I'm guessing my map not loading is due to the warning messages.

Any tips if known would be appreciated. Thanks in advance if so.

```
 loadScript(this, mapResources + '/jquery.js')
 .then(() => {
    loadScript(this, mapResources + '/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.1.min.js')

    .then(() => {
        loadScript(this, mapResources + '/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill.js') 

        .then(() => {
          $("document").ready(function(){
            $('#world-map-125').vectorMap({map: 'world_mill'});
          })
```

Comment: It sounds like jvectormap specifically is trying to reference `window` and Locker Service probably doesn't like it. Does your div have [`lwc:dom="manual"` set?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library) Keep in mind not all third party libraries will work within LWCs.

Comment: Hi @nbrown, Thanks for this tip. I was not aware of the requirement for lwc:dom="manual".  I've tried to use it generally now, not just for the map itself but to test out if I can apply changes using jQuery (I just wanted to ensure making changes via jQuery itself works to then know if it would be a map issue itself).  On testing the following  $("p").append('<span id="add_here">new-dynamic-text</span>'); or  $("p").text("Hello world!"); within my   $("document").ready(function(){ function no change occurs to <p lwc:dom="manual"></p>  Do you know if jQuery should be allowed to change the DOM?

Comment: I've never used jQuery in an LWC myself, but there are [examples](https://niksdeveloper.com/salesforce/include-jquery-in-lwc-lightning-web-component/) online of using it. I would avoid using `document.ready()` as your event handler because the `document` global is [not directly accessible](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_locker_global_access) in an LWC. You can just call your jQuery methods once the library is loaded.

Comment: Hi @mbrown, thanks for your help on this.  I ended up having to park it while looking into other alternatives also. I'll try to get back to this over the coming days re: a further update.  In the meantime I moved onto the Leaflet.js library & have been trying that out also. I'll retry the jVectorMap POC over the next few days. Thanks

Comment: Hi @mbrown, Sorry I never got back to this.  Thanks again for your initial help. It was appreciated.